# Step Progress Bar Icons

Tags: css

I'm trying to set up a little step progress bar that only has an icon for the current step. I've gotten so far as to have a default icon of sorts, but can't figure out how to clear it for non-active steps.

In the code below, I tried playing with pseudo classes but that didn't seem to work. I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

```
    .step-indicator-container {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }

    .step-indicator li {
        list-style-type: none;
        width: 33.33%;
        float: left;
        font-size: 12px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #7d7d7d;
    }

    .step-indicator li:before {
        font-family: "FontAwesome";
        content: "\f276";
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: white;
    }

    .step-indicator li:after {
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #7d7d7d;
        top: 15px;
        left: -50%;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .step-indicator li:not(.active):nth-of-type(2) > *::before {
        content: none;
    }

    .step-indicator li:first-child:after {
        content: none;
    }

    .step-indicator li.active {
        color: #0052e7;
    }

    .step-indicator li.active:before {
        border-color: #0052e7;
    }

    .step-indicator li.active+li:after {
        background-color: #0052e7;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML? [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53245334/edit) and add a code snippet so we can see it in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this answer, I am assuming the following is your HTML structure:

```
<div class="step-indicator-container">
  <ul class="step-indicator">
    <li></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The issue is with the following declaration:

```
.step-indicator li:not(.active):nth-of-type(2) > *::before {
    content: none;
}
```

This is targeting the `::before` of a *descendant* of the `li` tag. However, you actually put your symbol on the `::before` of the `li` tag itself, not a descendant. Therefore, that's what you need to be targeting. Furthermore, `content: none` eliminates the `::before`, so you actually want `content: ""`. Here's what I think you actually want:

```
.step-indicator li:not(.active)::before {
    content: "";
}
```

And here's the full code snippet (note I replaced your symbol with the $):

```css
.step-indicator-container {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.step-indicator li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #7d7d7d;
}

.step-indicator li:before {
    content: "$";
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
}

.step-indicator li:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #7d7d7d;
    top: 15px;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.step-indicator li:not(.active)::before {
    content: "";
}

.step-indicator li:first-child:after {
    content: none;
}

.step-indicator li.active {
    color: #0052e7;
}

.step-indicator li.active:before {
    border-color: #0052e7;
}

.step-indicator li.active+li:after {
    background-color: #0052e7;
}
```

```html
<div class="step-indicator-container">
  <ul class="step-indicator">
    <li></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```